# What to do when Ctrl-C won't kill running job?

Tags: command-line, bash, job-control

Sometimes, processes ignore the SIGINT signal sent by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> in Bash. For instance, `man` and `vi`. Assuming you don't want to google or read the manual on how to exit the running process, is there any key sequence that will **always** work (without leaving the terminal)?

Answer (score 202, accepted):

Send the **SIGQUIT** signal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd>.

```
.. $ sleep 10
^\Quit
```

→ This is equivalent to `kill -3 pid`. Programs run in user-space don't ignore sigquit.

There is also a set of *Magic SysRq* keyboard shortcuts. One of the more interesting ones is this: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>SysRq</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>. It kills every process on the current virtual console. If one of your ttys is completely and utterly broken, this can be used to *go back*. On the tty running X.org, it can be used to kill X without mercy.

The SysRq key is, on most keyboards, the same as the Print Key. On my notebook, it can be invoked using the Fn key; I.e. Alt→Fn→Print→k in that order.

Here are some of the basic process management shortcuts:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>: pause a
  process (plus `bg` to resume in the background, `fg` to raise to foreground)
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>: politely ask the process to
  shut down now
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd>: mercilessly kill the process that is
  currently in the foreground
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>SysRq</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>: Write data to disk (always do this before killing anything important)
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>SysRq</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>, <kbd>k</kbd>: mercilessly kill all current
  processes on a given virtual console
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>SysRq</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>, <kbd>b</kbd>: mercilessly reboot without unmounting,
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>SysRq</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>, <kbd>e</kbd>, <kbd>i</kbd>, <kbd>s</kbd>, <kbd>u</kbd>, <kbd>b</kbd>: Safely **r**eboot **e**ven **i**f the **s**ystem is **u**tterly **b**roken,

Note: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, in contrast to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd>, also works for `man`, `vi`, `less`, and the like.

When in doubt, the follwing procedure will almost always work:

```
~$ sleep 10
^Z
[5]+  Stopped              sleep 10
~$ ps
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 4804 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
 6207 pts/0    00:00:00 sleep
 6208 pts/0    00:00:00 ps
~$ kill -9 6207
[5]+  Killed                  sleep 10
~$
```

^Z of course indicates that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> has been pressed.

---

For a more in-depth look at Shells and Terminals, also see my answers on:

- [What are shells?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14866/what-are-shells/14870#14870)
- [Why is a virtual terminal "virtual", and what/why/where is the "real" terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14284/why-is-a-virtual-terminal-virtual-and-what-why-where-is-the-real-terminal/14294#14294)

Comment: Works for "sleep 10" but still doesn't work for "man" or "vi". Obviously "kill -9 pid" does work at killing both processes. Am I missing something?

Comment: **Ctrl+Z** works with things like less, man, vi and so on. You can then kill them by doing a `ps` to see their process id and kill them using `kill pid` or, if you don't care about other instances of the program, `killall vi`. In any case, Ctrl-Z always seems to work.

Comment: You can also do `kill %%` to kill the last job and `kill %5` where 5 is the job number shown in `jobs`.

Comment: Ctrl-\ sends a **SIGQUIT**, not a SIGKILL. There are some important differences between SIGQUIT and SIGKILL. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGQUIT

Comment: Juliano, I feel a bit silly now.. But i've edited the answer. Thank you!

Comment: Never ever do Alt+SysRq+b. Instead do  Alt+SysRq+reisub to prevent damage to your system.

Comment: There is no limitation that programs run in userspace have to honour SIGQUIT. C-\ does not "mercilessly kill the process that is currently in the foreground" any more than C-c does, both are trappable.

Comment: On laptops without a print key, how do we get Sysrq? For Surface pro keyboards could it be `Fn + Space`?

Comment: Does `Alt+SysRq+r, e, i, s, u, b` mean pressing `r,e,i,s,u,b` in sequence? And not holding it down.

Comment: @CMCDragonkai Yes, it means holding down Alt and SysRq and then pressing r, e, i, s, u and b in sequence. The SysRq key could be anywhere on your keyboard, I'm not sure how you'd find out which one it is.

Comment: @StefanoPalazzo Could you correct the broken images?

Comment: How do I press `Ctrl`+`\ ` when there is no `\ ` key in my keyboard layout?

Comment: can we catch CTRL+Z on node js using process.on('eventName')?

Comment: How am I just learning about this?? +1+1

Comment: None of these keys are working for me.

Answer (score 18):

You can try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd>

Comment: Doesn't work with either `man` or `vi`.

Comment: worked ubuntu 16.04

Comment: I had to hit Ctrl+\ twice before it did anything.  However, it core dumped.

Answer (score 11):

Sometimes the <kbd>CTRL+C</kbd> is getting sent to the wrong program or input channel. This is especially common with editors such as `vi`, with commands with piped output, complex bash commands involving loops, etc.

A simple, quick solution is to suspend the job <kbd>CTRL+Z</kbd> and then kill it by job number: `kill %1` or `kill -9 %1`, etc.

Answer (score 11):

- Try one of these:

  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd>

  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd>

---

- Or:

  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> and then run:

  `kill %1`

Where `%1` is the number of job which was returned when you pressed <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd>. Add `-9` to force the kill.

---

When you're in text console, you could also try: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>SysRq</kbd>. The kernel should kill the process.

Or <kbd>SysRq</kbd>-<kbd>k</kbd>, kill all processes on the current virtual console (can kill X and svgalib programs as well).

> Note: When magic SysRq keys are used to kill a frozen graphical
>   program, the program has no chance to restore text mode. This can make
>   everything unreadable.

See: [Magic SysRq key and its command combinations.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key)

Answer (score 4):

It's possible, that you changed the shortcut of copy from:

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>

To

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>

That way, when you try to kill a process, the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> doesn't work.

Try to replace the copy shortcut to <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

Comment: Changing copy shortcut is irrelevant to force a process to be terminated!

Comment: Can you please expand on your answer a little?  Step by step would be ideal, primarily so the OP can follow along with your suggestion. :)

Comment: This actually helped me. I'm used to CTRL+C on MacOS, and didn't realise the Ubuntu command was CTRL+SHIFT+C

Comment: I never realized that is what I did! Thanks. CTRL+SHIFT+C works

Comment: This exactly what I did ><! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

To quit from **man**, use `q`
To leave **vi** use `:q`

Answer (score 1):

Open Terminal → Preferences → Shortcuts and search if by mistake you have replaced any key with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

Answer (score -1):

Try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd>

If you are using ubuntu 10.04 you wanna enable this key to work.

To enable <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Backspace</kbd>

Goto System-->Preferences-->Keyboard

Select the **Layouts tab** and click on the **Layout Options**.

Select **Key sequence to kill the X server** and enable **<kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> +<kbd>Backspace</kbd>**.

Note:

Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Backspace</kbd> will restart your X server.

Comment: Edited the question to make it clear I want to kill the process from within the terminal.