# How do I open a terminal in unity without window's top bar?

Tags: unity, gnome-terminal, window, titlebar

I would like (in Unity) to open a terminal as startup application; I created a simple script

```
gnome-terminal --profile=Startup --geometry 40x24+920+300
```

and put it in my startup applications. Anyway I would like the terminal window to appear WITHOUT its button's bar ont the top of the window itself (the one with the `maximize`, `minimize` and `exit` buttons). Is that possible? I cannot find any way to do it on the Internet.

Comment: Why not use the virtual terminal then: http://askubuntu.com/questions/33078/what-is-a-virtual-terminal-for ?

Answer (score 3):

I found a better (in my opinion) solution, which is `tilda` terminal emulator.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the terminal [screenlet](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Terminal+Screenlet?content=74844).

```
sudo apt-get install screenlets-all
```

Comment: Can you provide instructions on installing this?

Comment: It's in the default screenlets-all iirc.  sudo apt-get install screenlets-all and use the config gui.  It's really straightforward.

Comment: Great then!  Add it into your answer so its an "answer" ;-)