# How can access the Windows desktop from Ubuntu if they are on the same hard drive?

Tags: remote-desktop

I don't want just a command box, but a separate window that lets me in to Windows. I've seen it before so I know you can.

Tried running Remmina  but its not letting me connect.

Comment: I think what you are asking is impossible. You can run Windows in a virtual machine, but it will be a separate installation from the one you have in your hard drive. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/284992/run-both-at-the-same-time-windows-and-ubuntu You can run some Windows software in Ubuntu via Wine. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wine for more on wine.

Comment: Do you want a virtual machine? Look into virtualbox or vmware

Answer (score 0):

I think it is impossible. You can access Windows's files and run some software using Wine.
You cannot run your installed Windows from Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking is not possible. (Usually)

That said, it *may* be possible to load your windows partition in Virtual Box. 
https://www.virtualbox.org/

You can install Virtual Box from the Software Center in Ubuntu and create a new virtual machine that uses the windows partition of your hard drive rather than a virtual hard disk. **However** this usually doesn't work because windows will detect that you have changed your core hardware configuration and will simply not boot. There's quite a few more reasons this will probably not work, but I'll stop there unless you want more detail. :)

You can still access the files on your windows partition. This is rather easy to do, just open the file manager in Ubuntu and you will see your windows partition on the left side of the screen. Your files from windows will be in there somewhere based on what version of windows you have installed.