# Virtualbox or Wine?

Tags: installed-programs

What is the function of virtual box and wine ?
And if they have the same function which is better?

I got confused in choosing program to load my windows stuff

Comment: It is actually virtual box in the title

Comment: You can [edit] your question. But I've done that already for you.

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/284992/run-both-at-the-same-time-windows-and-ubuntu/285016#285016 for more on a type of program called **virtual machines**. Virtual Box is one such program.

Answer (score 1):

Virtualbox allows you to install other operating systems inside Ubuntu. You can install a real Windows this way.

All programs will run in it. But this requires a lot of RAM an CPU power, because a virtual machine can use only part of these resources.

Wine allows you to run ***some*** Windows programs in Ubuntu. Not all programs will run well, some will not run at all.

Answer (score 1):

#### Wine

Pros: You can run some Windows apps without needing Windows.

Cons: Only some Windows apps will work.

#### VirtualBox

Pros: You can run virtually any Windows app.

Cons: You need a pretty beefy computer to run VirtualBox effectively, and a full install of Windows.

If the apps you need, run via Wine, then I would say that is the best choice. If not, VirtualBox is a good choice.

> If you have a copy of Windows with a valid license and if your hardware is powerful enough, then virtualbox would definitely be the way to go.
>
> However, lacking a copy of Windows with a valid license or lacking sufficient hardware, then wine, playonlinux or crossover (I *think* that's what it is called) would probably be the better choice

Reference: [This post by *anewguy*](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1916805&p=11648126#post11648126) at [Wine Vs Virtual Box](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1916805&p=11648126)

Comment: But anyway is a 2.2 GHZ computer with 1 GB RAM considered beefy now?

Comment: You need to attribute this.   You copied this from http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1916805&p=11648126.

Comment: @JonathanWillianto Good God no. "Beefy" is at least Core i5 and 8GB RAM.

Comment: Upgrade that RAM to 4GB and it will run VBox with Windows 7 easily.  I do it all the time on mine, and in fact, I've run all of these OS's at once on 2.2GHz dual core with 6GB of RAM:  4 instances of Windows 7, Ubuntu 15.04, CentOS 4.8, and Windows 10.  That's a total of 7 OS's running on one machine.  You should be able to run Windows 7 if you upgrade your RAM to at least 4GB

Comment: I have run VB for years on 4GB RAM and 2GHz processor.  Just recently got a 4x processor @2 GHz and 8GB RAM.  It was a little sluggish before, and now less sluggish, but for my work, it is suitable even for working with video editing. --- 1GB RAM?  -  No way!