# Is it possible to Debian Ubuntu and windows without restart your PC

Tags: windows-10, debian

Is it possible to  Debian Ubuntu and windows without restart your PC﻿. If it's how can i do it ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run both at the same time, Windows and Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/284992/run-both-at-the-same-time-windows-and-ubuntu)

Comment: "Debian" is not a verb, so please [edit] to fix that and clarify overall.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `virtualbox` [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VirtualBox),[2](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) to manage virtual machines inside your current operating system such as on Windows, you can run various operating systems without needing to boot into it.