# Can I "dual boot" with Windows to where I can switch without restart?

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10

I have yet to install Ubuntu yet, as I'd rather this question be answered first so I can use whatever method may be needed.  I know this is possible on Chrome OS, but can I do it with Windows 10? 
If not, what can I do to achieve a similar result?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run both at the same time, Windows and Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/284992/run-both-at-the-same-time-windows-and-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

No. Multi-boot is just that: more than one operating system installed to some boot accessible storage, one of which is chosen at boot time.

If you want to run a Linux or Windows VM on the other, you can use something like Virtual Box.

There is also Wine, which allows for some level of support for running Windows executables on Linux.

Comment: Wine is so unstable, is there other option to run window software?

Comment: Run Windows? Wine is fine for many things, but we have to expect it isn't going to be perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you need, asides from using a VM as jdv suggests, you could take a look at the Windows Subsystem for Linux in Windows 10.

[WSL installation instructions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10)

It doesn't give you a GUI but it gets you a bash shell, therefore access to lots of handy stuff otherwise not easily available in Windows.