# Connect monitor to headless server

Tags: server, monitor

I've inherited a server running on Ubuntu which has a keyboard connected, but no monitor.
Now there's been a network problem and I'm currently unable to connect via ssh (not even ping works). Still, calculations started by someone else might be running.
For diagnosis, I plugged a monitor to vga, but this monitor gets no signal and stays black.
How can I activate the monitor?
I don't need a GUI, seeing bash would already be OK.

Comment: It would be helpful to share exactly what server hardware you are running on, what version of Ubuntu, etc.

Comment: As I said, at the moment I can't get any information out of it. I am not the one who configured it, so I don't know details.
The whole thing is from end 2010.
Hardware is an ordinary cheap computer.

Comment: I can again ssh to that computer and see it's up and working. Therefore
1) I do not need to plug a monitor anymore, at least not now.
2) I can give more precise information: The OS is ubuntu server 10.04.3 LTS

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Pressing a key on the keyboard may take the display out of sleep mode and cause something to appear on the screen. Also, try switching [virtual terminals](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33078/what-is-a-virtual-terminal-for) using `ctrl-alt-f1`, `ctrl-alt-f2`, etc.

Comment: sadly, this didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem. My issue was that HDMI cable was unidirectional, there's one way to plug it in from monitor to computer. Try swapping the cable (if you're still working on this 4 years after asking). :)