# Fn + F2 what does it do?

Tags: screen

When I prees Fn+F2 my screen turn black what does it do? I want to know what change does it make.
When at window7 I press Fn+F2 it will turn on wifi.
After I restart nothing happen , did it will make eror?

sorry about my bad english

Comment: I guess you're on a laptop, aren't you ? The result of Fn+Fxx depends of your laptop and its bios, and the support or lack of support of its specifics on Linux... What laptop model are you using ?

Comment: yes i'm using laptop asus brand,, but when i press again Fn+F2 after restart nothing happen ...

Comment: It is probably a software dependent keypress, only work in windows... we need the model name and number, "asus" is the maker so it is too generic to look up specific problems about certain laptops.

Answer (score 2):

After pressing <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, try and see if <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> bring you back to the GUI. It sounds from your description that <kbd>Fn</kbd> may be behaving like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>. If that's the case, then it's switching virtual consoles. The seventh virtual console is typically your GUI; lower-numbered ones behave as text terminals.

See:

- [virtual console (wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_console)
- [What is a virtual terminal for?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33078/what-is-a-virtual-terminal-for)
- [What does "Ctrl + Alt + F12" do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/277517/what-does-ctrl-alt-f12-do)

However, **if the screen turns *completely* black**, then that's probably not what's going on. In that case, it probably dims or turns off the screen.

So another combination should brighten or turn on the screen. Assuming you've tried pressing <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> again to see if it toggles things back to the way they were before, you might try <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> or <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> to see if you can reverse the effect of <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>.

**If this was a one-time occurrence** and the question is whether or not it represents a problem you have to worry about, the answer is *probably not.* In that case, I'm not sure of the cause, but it could be:

- There was a bug, and an update fixed it (perhaps an update installed before the first time you pressed <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, but which did not take effect until the next boot-up).
- Some other key was accidentally pressed at the same time.
- Some program interpreted that key as input, and triggered a problem.

All of these explanations suggest a bug, but there are probably other explanations. If the problem happens again, then I recommend editing your question to provide more information (or posting a new one if the situation has changed considerably). In that case, the main question will be whether or not it's a bug and, if so, what package to report the bug as affecting.

Comment: after restart nothing happen when i press again Fn+F2

Comment: @shukry I've added another section to my answer which might address this, if I understand you correctly.

Comment: i'm sure I not pressing other button, but I need to know if it is affecting system?? if no, doesn't matter.

Comment: @shukry There's probably no problem. But I recommend waiting to see if other people post answers here. You might get more ideas that way.