# Disabling desktop environment in Ubuntu 16.04 for a specific kernel/boot option

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel

I have a system with multiple kernels installed and would like one of the kernels to boot up without the GUI/Desktop environment.  I assume this can be done in the grub-customizer tool by editing the boot script for that specific kernel.  Here's the script from the specific kernel I wish to modify:

```sh
    recordfail
    load_video
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,msdos1'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,$        else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 0c2ea0ab-08e3-42b6-8752-4b1aaad7bc1d
    fi
    echo    'Loading Linux 4.8.15-rt10 ...'
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.15-rt10 root=UUID=0c2ea0ab-08e3-42b6-8752-4b1aaad7bc1d ro  quiet splash 8250.nr_uart$ $vf_handoff
    echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.8.15-rt10
```

Should I change `gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode`? If so, to what?  Thanks

---

I also followed the last answer for [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/378046/how-to-run-ubuntu-xubuntu-in-a-complete-non-gui-mode) question, adding 'text' to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT and uncommenting `GRUB_TERMINAL="console"`.

---

I've figured out the command `systemctl set-default multi-user.target` forces console at boot and `systemctl set-default graphical.target` reverts back to GUI at boot, however, I want to implement this using a specific boot option.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I am not totally sure, but would try an educated guess: 
In this line `linux /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.15-rt10 root=UUID=0c2ea0ab-08e3-42b6-8752-4b1aaad7bc1d ro quiet splash 8250.nr_uart$ echo 'Loading initial ramdisk ...'`
enter 'text' behind 'ro'.

Comment: Just tried it, still starts a desktop session.

Comment: I also tried 'ro quiet splash text' and removed '$vf_handoff', still same result.

Comment: Problem is I don't know the grub-customizer tool. For testing you can edit the boot script by hitting "e" while grub2 shows the boot menu (you probably know that). Inserting "text" as I described works on my machine.

Comment: Weird, using 'e' in grub and having only 'ro  quiet splash text' still boots desktop.  I wonder if maybe startx is in a startup file somewhere or something?

Comment: Do you have Ubuntu 16.04?  Supposedly 16.04 works differently and the graphical launch is handled by systemd, see my edits above.

Comment: Does that help? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/164005/non-graphical-boot-with-systemd