# How to boot into terminal

Tags: gnome

I have Ubuntu Server installed in an Intel NUC, and I later installed the Gnome desktop.

Is there an easy way to boot in terminal mode and switch to desktop if something I need to do is easier using desktop, then switch back to terminal mode?

Comment: possible duplicates: [How do I disable X at boot time so that the system boots in text mode?](https://askubuntu.com/q/16371/253474), [How to run ubuntu/xubuntu in a complete non-gui mode](https://askubuntu.com/q/378046/253474), [How to start Ubuntu in Console mode](https://askubuntu.com/q/859630/253474), [Booting into text mode in 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/q/870221/253474)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I disable X at boot time so that the system boots in text mode?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16371/how-do-i-disable-x-at-boot-time-so-that-the-system-boots-in-text-mode)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to start Ubuntu in Console mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/859630/how-to-start-ubuntu-in-console-mode)