# VM shows a black screen after login

Tags: 16.04, virtualbox, virtualization

I am trying to connect on my virtual machine, in order to work on Ubuntu 16.04.
It allows me to log into the vagrant machine, but a black screen appears afterward and nothing happens.

[image: screenshot of a blank VM window]

I didn’t do a backup on my work and I am afraid I might lose it all and have to reinstall the VM. 
Do I have a virtualization problem or what can I do to make the VM work as before?

The Vagrant-Machine appears like [Running]:

[image: screenshot of the title bar]

It allows me to log into the machine but that’s all:

[image: screenshot of the login screen]

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! Can you switch to a [virtual console](https://askubuntu.com/q/33078/250300) using `Ctrl+Alt+F2`, for example? If not, can you boot to the [recovery mode](https://askubuntu.com/q/92556/250300)? I think your user data remain intact but you should definitely start making backups. You should at least make a VirtualBox snapshot before further manipulations.

Comment: I tried using CTRL+ALT+F2 and nothing happend . The Vagrant-Machine appears like [Running] , I added a new photo to show that.

Comment: Can you not `vagrant ssh` to the VM?

Comment: how can I do that ? I am also new when it comes to VM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to Boot it,  <kbd>F12</kbd>, and check for the virtualization.
If there is nothing you can do, reinstall it and learn how to back up your virtual machine from time to time to be sure it won't happen again.

Did you shutdown properly the machine after using it?

Comment: I might have not power off it properly. Last time I kinda forced the shutdown since I needed to do an update to the pc.