# After Lubuntu install shows white screen with black line

Tags: boot, graphics, lubuntu, intel-graphics

The computer just showing a white screen with flashing black line at the top left after a clean install of Lubuntu (latest version I think 18?). Previously had Windows 10 if that helps.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd> shows a jumble of distorted characters.

I'm on an [HP Stream](https://support.hp.com/gb-en/document/c04490851) with Intel Celeron @2.00GHz with 2GB RAM.

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! What did you see before this? For example, does the computer boot, could you log in? Can you switch to a [virtual console](https://askubuntu.com/q/33078/250300) using Ctrl+Alt+F2, for example? Please [edit] your question to add all necessary details.

Comment: Nothing before it, and ctrl alt f2 shows jumble of distorted characters.

Comment: Thank you for the update. If the keyboard shortcut changed anything (even if the view is still not readable), it would likely be a graphics issue. Could you add information about your graphics card?

Comment: I don't really know much about it but I'll check online now.

Comment: Here is a link with the most specs I could find: https://support.hp.com/gb-en/document/c04490851 it says Intel HD under graphics but nothing else.

Comment: Don't worry about helping me but still feel free to answer question for someone with same problem.

Comment: If there are any steps you performed to resolve your problem, _you_ should [answer your question](https://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer). Anyone else trying that would be just guessing… If the problem just disappeared, your question should be closed as “cannot be reproduced”.