# ctrl+alt+f8 pulls blank screen. What is this for?

Tags: command-line

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>f1</kbd> through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>f6</kbd> will pull up terminals and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>f7</kbd> pulls up the xserver.

But <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>f8</kbd> pulls a blank screen with a blinking cursor.

I can't type anything. Does this serve a purpose?

Comment: This Q could be duplicated to http://askubuntu.com/questions/277517/what-does-ctrl-alt-f12-do, which has a good general explanation answering this. Likewise http://askubuntu.com/questions/14284/why-is-a-virtual-terminal-virtual-and-what-why-where-is-the-real-terminal?rq=1 is good. I'm new to StackOverflow / AskUbuntu - how can I duplicate a Q?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Only virtual terminals 1 through 7 are used by default on Ubuntu. Virtual terminals beyond 7 are left unused. But if you use multiple logins using the "Switch Account" feature, then these will go from 8 onwards.

Comment: Is there a limit to virtual terminals? What will occur if there are more inactive user sessions than TTYs?