# What unused key combinations are available for use with AutoKey or other apps?

Tags: shortcut-keys, autokey

I tried setting up a macro using AutoKey and assigned <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>f8</kbd> thinking it probably wouldn't be used for something else. Unfortunately it turned my entire screen black except for a cursor in the top left corner! I found a mention of that function [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/252929/ctrlaltf8-pulls-blank-screen-what-is-this-for).

Where can I find a list of key combinations that are unused (assuming there are any)?

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of places I can think of to check for used key combinations.

- If you have **dconf-editor** installed you could try navigating to **org>gnome>desktop>wm>key bindings**.
- Another way is through System Settings->Keyboard->Shortcuts, however this groups key combinations by function, such as sound, windows, so it's not as easy to see all the keys in one hit.

Answer (score 1):

The most useful tool would provide a simple way to list all current keybindings in sorted order.

The answer from rods helps a lot!  But dconf-editor doesn't seem to let us export the information, sort it, save it etc.  The `gsettings` tool accesses the same dconf database from the command line.  So far the best I've found is this:

```
gsettings list-recursively | egrep 'keybinding|media-keys'| sort -k 3 | uniq
```

Unfortunately it doesn't list the Unity bindings, i.e. the ones which are listed by holding down the `Super` key, like `Alt-F10` or `Super-A`.  And I'm guessing there are more since this is pretty ad-hoc.   And I don't know why it produces duplicates.  I've just removed them via `uniq`.

More insights would be appreciated.  This was on Trusty 14.04 LTS.