# How to run commands if unity is not working?

Tags: unity, 13.04, command-line

I'm running ubuntu 13.04 on a compaq pressario cq56. After system update unity and terminal will not load. I've read some forums on how to fix the unity problem but without terminal I can't use them, and I've found forums about the terminal issue but cannot fix it without software center which I cannot load.

I can go into root terminal from recovery mode but that seems to be ready only and will not let me install or modify files. Any help I can get to get unity or terminal back would be great. If this isn't possible I'll just try to copy some data to a flash drive and reinstall.

Comment: Related (but probably not a duplicate): [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](http://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears), [What is a virtual terminal for?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/33078/what-is-a-virtual-terminal-for), [Why is a virtual terminal “virtual”, and what/why/where is the “real” terminal?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14284/why-is-a-virtual-terminal-virtual-and-what-why-where-is-the-real-terminal)

Comment: I was able to remount the root shell to read write with mount -o remount,rw / .  I ran that with networking and was able to install unity. Im now working on starting unity, but I should be able find that somewhere. It may also be a graphics driver error as indixated by other unity missing forums.

Answer (score 3):

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to go in tty1 and run whichever command you wish. To come back in tty7 (where the graphic environment is usually running), use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>.

Answer (score -1):

You can try reinstalling the ubuntu desktop.
You can use Ctrl+Alt+F1
Enter your username then password

then you can do this to reinstall unity and terminal :)

```
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

Comment: This will only reinstall the meta-package for the Ubuntu desktop. The programs and configuration files that make up the desktop stay untouched.