# How to really clear the terminal?

Tags: command-line, xterm

I can issue the `clear` command or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> to clear the current Ubuntu terminal, but this just shifts previous output upwards and if you use mouse scroll or <kbd>PgUP</kbd> and <kbd>PgDown</kbd> keys it's hard to distinguish where the output of previous command ends and output of current command begins.

Is there a way to **really** clear the terminal so I won't see previous command results?

Comment: Press Ctrl+L **twice** and you get blank!

Comment: On mac os and iTERM, cmd + k does the trick for me.

Comment: ctrl+L twice works on mac os x vscode integrated terminal

Comment: To clarify the MacOS commands: `cmd.K` - clear terminal, can't scroll up || `ctrl.L` - clear screen, scroll up for history || multiple `ctrl.L` - clear multiple screens. Can see the empty prompt for each clear, and will be able to see history prior to the number of clears

Answer (score 592, accepted):

Yes, the command you're looking for is

```
reset
```

In contrast to `clear`, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, `reset` will actually completely re-initialise the [terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14866/what-are-shells/14870#14870), instead of just clearing the screen. However, it won't re-instantiate the shell (bash). That means that bash's *state* is the same as before, just as if you were merely clearing the screen.

As @Ponkadoodle mentions in the comments, this command should do the [same thing more quickly](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/335648/128893):

```
tput reset
```

---

From the other answers:

- You can set a **Keyboard Shortcut** to `reset` the terminal, as [explained by **towolf**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25077/how-to-really-clear-the-terminal/25346#25346).
- If you're running **Kubuntu**, and your terminal is Konsole, you need to go to *Edit → Clear history*, since `reset` doesn't work the same way there, [as UncleZeiv notes](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25077/how-to-really-clear-the-terminal/25172#25172).

Comment: Probably doesn't matter for most users, but the behavior of `reset` is dependent on the terminal.

Comment: Personally I don't mind that something is left "up" along the scroller when I hit `^L`. I don't see it (that's what I want!), I don't feel it, and if suddenly I would *need* to restore what was there — no problem. `reset` in contrast is much harder tool — I'll use it when something went wrong with the terminal — like, when weird escape sequences accidentally ruined the display altogether.

Comment: @ulidtko: it does matter when you run consecutive sessions of programs with tons of output. If you scroll back it's easy to get confused about which execution printed something. I know perfectly well that more sophisticated solutions could be used in these cases, but nonetheless it's a scenario that comes about pretty often in quick & dirty debugging sessions.

Comment: @UncleZeiv colored prompt anchors usually help me to quickly find the needed spot. Though this is all just habits.

Comment: source ~./bash_profile to reset the bash.

Comment: There's also `tput reset` which visibly does the same thing, but completes instantaneously (whereas `reset` can take up to about 2 seconds before the prompt reappears).

Comment: This causes my putty.exe window to resize, would be nice to clear without that happening.

Comment: For anyone finding this answer via Google while they're actually on macOS & iTerm 2, it's possible to alias `reset` like `alias reset="reset && printf '\33c\e[3J'"` to get the same behavior.

Comment: How does this behave if I'm in an ssh session?

Comment: @Ponkadoodleyour comment would be improved by adding _why_ it is faster using `tput reset` vs just `reset`, thanks!

Comment: On Fedora `clear` works fine, but on Ubuntu doesn't, so I just use `alias clear="tput reset"` on Ubuntu.

Comment: `tput reset` does nothing for me

Comment: The `reset` and `clear` commands both just uselessly scroll. Neither one clears the terminal.

Comment: If `tput reset` doesn't clear your terminal, you may need to do `printf '\033[3J\033c'` instead but that is not portable to all terminals either.

Answer (score 186):

I was looking for this for a while and I found some genius that posted this:

```sh
clear && printf '\e[3J'
```

Clears the whole screen buffer, very clean. Works on OS X and believe it works fine on most *nix terminals.

For curious, this part `'\e[3J'` is a terminal escape command.

Comment: Hmm, works in xterm, Konsole and Linux VT, but doesn't in gnome-terminal...

Comment: Best answer. Even purges **tmux history** (as in *Ctrl+b PgUp*; `reset` fails to do so; tested in rxvt-unicode/urxvt; tmux-specific alternative: `clear && tmux clearhist`).

Comment: Thanks, that's super useful! What does `printf '\e[3J'` mean? How does it clean the buffer?

Comment: Great find! And for those who want the Bash-style reset on mac:
`nano ~/.bashrc`
and add
`alias reset="clear && printf '\e[3J'"`

Comment: be careful aliasing `reset` -- it does more than just clear the terminal. for example, if you accidentally print a binary file with random garbage that corrupts the terminal (e.g. disables echoing of typed characters), `reset` can usually fix that. of course aliasing is fine as long as you know how to `\override` an alias-shadowed command.

Comment: This is the only answer that works to clear Putty scrollback when accessing some SSH via Winders.

Comment: Can also be written as: `printf '\033c\e[3J'`

Comment: @FilipSpiridonov: This is a terminal escape code, similar to the codes that control color of text in your terminal. Some more info at this other answer: https://superuser.com/questions/555554/putty-clear-scrollback-from-commandline

Comment: Works on the Linux Sybsystem on Windows 10! I aliased `cls` to this command, so as not to mess with `clear` or `reset`.

Comment: Among all answers here, only this one work exactly list cmd-k on mac OS. FYI, I am using Mohave 10.14.3.

Comment: Great! It also works for linux subsystem in windows!

Comment: @Filip Spiridonov, `\e[3J` is the escape sequence that "Erase Saved Lines, xterm." (i.e. the scroll-back). Reference: https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html (search for `CSI Ps J`)

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 22.04 :)

Comment: Unlike the "accepted answer", this one does something.

Comment: This one helped me, thanks! :^)

Comment: You can also append in your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zprofile` with `alias clear="clear && printf '\e[3J'"`

Answer (score 51):

You can also assign a shortcut in gnome-terminal by going to *Edit → Keyboard Shortcuts*. I use<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

[image: reset and clear shortcut]

Comment: +1. I always have the Menubar hidden; so even after years and years of using gnome, I never thought to look for this. Thanks :-)

Comment: “Reset” do nothing for me, and “Reset and Clear” clear everything but does not re‑display the prompt. None of these menu entries behave like the “reset” command from a terminal.

Comment: As @Hibou57 said, my keyboard shortcut for "Reset" doesn't seem to do anything. Is this functionality broken in 14.04?

Comment: “Is this functionality broken in 14.04?”: this is the same with 12.04.

Comment: @Hibou57  "Reset and Clear" isn't expected to re-display the prompt, but if you hit Enter afterwards it should re-display the prompt.   Does that work for you?

Comment: The other answers only work if you're in the shell; this is the only one that works if you're in some other program (e.g. repl). Alternatively in Ubuntu 20.04 you can click burger => advanced => reset and clear

Answer (score 25):

Cross posting my answer from [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5367075/39648).

Use the following command to do a clear screen instead of merely adding new lines ...

```
printf "\033c"
```

yes that's a 'printf' on the bash prompt.

You will probably want to define an alias though...

```
alias cls='printf "\033c"'
```

#### Explanation

```
\033 == \x1B == 27 == ESC
```

So this becomes `<ESC>c` which is the VT100 escape code for resetting the terminal. [Here](http://www.termsys.demon.co.uk/vtansi.htm) is some more information on terminal escape codes.

#### Edit

Here are a few other ways of doing it...

```
printf "\ec" #\e is ESC in bash
echo -en "\ec" #thanks @Jonathon Reinhart.
# -e    Enable interpretation of of backslash escapes
# -n    Do not output a new line
```

## KDE

The above does not work on the KDE console (called Konsole) but there is hope! Use the following sequence of commands to clear the screen and the scroll-back buffer...

```
clear && echo -en "\e[3J"
```

Or perhaps use the following alias on KDE...

```
alias cls='clear && echo -en "\e[3J"'
```

I got the scroll-back clearing command from [here](https://superuser.com/a/59718/6765).

Answer (score 19):

run this command:

```
reset
```

This has the same effect as launching a new terminal.

Comment: When using putty, after running `reset`, I can still scroll up and see previous stuff. Is this an issue with PuTTY rather than `reset`?

Comment: @svish -- that's just a putty implementation issue or decision.

Comment: @jgbelacqua, Deal :)

Comment: Worked with MAC OS Terminal

Comment: @Bira No, `reset` doesn't clear the scrollback on macOS 10.14 Mojave.  You could try `seq 100; reset` to see scrollback still there.  On macOS terminal, `Cmd+K` can clear screen and scrollback.

Comment: The `reset` and `clear` commands scroll down. I can do that myself by simply scrolling. Useless.

Answer (score 11):

My favorite is `printf "\ec"`. This can also be `printf "\033c"` or `printf "\x1bc"`. That is an ansi escape sequence that miraculously clears the screen and buffer for the terminal output (for most standard terminals I have worked in it seems - I know it works in such as gnome-terminal, terminator, xterm, etc. on Ubuntu-like Linuxes)

I know this works in Linux Mint and Ubuntu 14.04, so I don't know why people are appending and prepedning things like `clear && echo -ne "\033c`. `printf "\ec"` has always worked for me.

Additionally, in my `.bashrc` I have a binding like this:

```
bind -x '"\C-t": printf "\ec"';
```

Now I press <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>t</kbd> all the time.

Comment: Do you know how could a mapping be created using the Windows key ? This snippet is really great, works exactly like Command-K on mac. Thank you.

Comment: @Niloct you can see if the terminal supports it with `xev` (just type `xev` in a terminal inside an x-session). From what I could tell, urxvt doesn't support it; while I didn't try in a tty, I am confident it would not be supported. I also doubt xterm or gnome-terminal would support this. It's tricky with ansi-escapes. Cheers and sorry for late reply.

Comment: Alright @dylnmc, I appreciate it. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 9):

Here are all the ways you can clear the terminal screen in Unix:

```
clear               # only clear visible screen
clear && clear      # clear buffer as well
tput clear          # same as clear but by sending escape seq
reset               # clear + reset internal terminal state + 1sec delay
tput reset          # same as reset but without 1sec delay
stty sane           # don't clear screen but reset some terminal options
echo -e "\033c"     # same as tput reset but hardcoded escape seq
printf "\033c"      # same as tput reset but hardcoded escape seq
setterm -reset      # same as tput reset, setterm has friendlier commands
```

Comment: The `clear` and `reset` commands only scroll down. They don't really do anything useful.

Answer (score 5):

Well it really depends, if you are using `Konsole` for instance even `reset` doesn't prevent you to scroll past the first line. In that case you have to use some feature of the particular terminal you are using. For `Konsole`, it's `Edit > Clear History`.

Answer (score 5):

I have found the following to be quite successful with Kubuntu:

```
alias clc="echo -en '\033c\033[3J'"
```

You can use `cls` to keep with the Windows tradition, use the Matlab version `clc`, or one of your own. Good luck!

Answer (score 5):

If you're using yakuake or Konsole, try
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>.

Source: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=309008

Comment: Thank you! Very useful. It took me quite some time to find it.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively to `reset`, you can do `echo -e "\033c"`, or have in your `.bashrc`, something like `alias cls="echo -ne '\033c'"`

The UNIX/Linux StackExchange, has a thread on this: [How to clear terminal completely? (unix.stackexchange.com)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26975/how-to-clear-terminal-completely), as well as SuperUser : [Clear terminal using keyboard shortcut (superuser.com)](https://superuser.com/questions/299903/clear-terminal-using-keyboard-shortcut).

Answer (score 3):

Another alternative to the @Hibou57 answer:

```
# The Octal Way
alias clear="echo -e '\033c\c'"
```

OR

```
# The Hex Way
alias clear="echo -e '\x1b\c'"
```

Basically this will have exactly the same effect, it will print the `^[` character (which clear your terminal) and does not output the trailing new line.

Comment: Slight correction: it prints the `^[` character (ESC) _followed by_ the `c` character, not just the `^[` character alone.  Combined, these amount to the "RIS" terminal code, which causes a reset. More info: https://www.xfree86.org/4.8.0/ctlseqs.html