# Key binding stops keyboard input echoing, and messes up the PS1 prompt

Tags: command-line, bash

I want Bash to clear the scrollback history when I press `Ctrl+L`, especially when I'm running a command with a lot of output; I want to scrollback to the first output line, without overshooting into previous output.  And starting a new tab, then switching back to the previous tab and closing it, is not really an option; on my laptop that's `Ctrl+Shift+T`, `Ctrl+Fn+PgDn`, `Ctrl+D`, which is a bit of a handful to type.  Following the advice in [How to really clear the terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25077/how-to-really-clear-the-terminal/25079), I added the following line to my `.bashrc` file, after the `PS1` definition:

```
PS1="\u@\h \w\n\$ "
bind -x '"\C-L": tput reset'
```

However, I then found that after cancelling a long-running Bash command, the terminal stopped echoing standard input when I type, and started showing a modified `PS1` prompt.  I finally narrowed it down to pressing `Ctrl+L`, then starting and interrupting a long-running command (for this example `find / | head`).

```
hwalters@Wintermute ~
$ 
hwalters@Wintermute ~
$ 
hwalters@Wintermute ~
$ (press Ctrl+L)
hwalters@Wintermute ~
$ find / | head
/
/proc
/proc/fb
/proc/fs
/proc/fs/ext4
/proc/fs/ext4/dm-0
/proc/fs/ext4/dm-0/options
/proc/fs/ext4/dm-0/mb_groups
/proc/fs/ext4/dm-0/es_shrinker_info
/proc/fs/ext4/nvme0n1p2
hwalters@Wintermute ~
$ hwalters@Wintermute ~
$ hwalters@Wintermute ~
$ hwalters@Wintermute ~
$ hello
hwalters@Wintermute ~
$ world
hwalters@Wintermute ~
$
```

I've included the results of pressing `Enter` a few times, both before and after it goes wrong.  Note the two output lines `hello` and `world`, which were shown after I entered `echo hello` and `echo world`; the `echo` commands and parameters were not shown as I typed, but were executed.

Note, this does *not* happen if I enter `tput reset` instead of pressing `Ctrl+L`, so it's some combination of that and the key binding.  I originally thought it might be a combination of the screen reset and the coloured prompt I generally use, but it happens with the vanilla prompt in this example as well.  Any ideas?

If it makes any difference, I'm using Gnome Terminal (3.18.3) in Ubuntu (16.04).