# What is terminal initialization by reset command?

Tags: command-line

What is terminal initialization by `reset` command? When should `reset` command be used?

Answer (score 1):

`reset` will actually completely re-initialise the [terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14866/what-are-shells/14870#14870), instead of just clearing the screen. However, it won't re-instantiate the shell (bash). That means that bash's state is the same as before, just as if you were merely clearing the screen.

Answer (score 1):

For me:

```
$ tput reset | od -t x1z 
0000000 1b 63 1b 5b 21 70 1b 5b 3f 33 3b 34 6c 1b 5b 34  ..c.[!p.[?3;4l.[4.
0000020 6c 1b 3e                                         .l...
0000023
```

*... cleansed a bit in the 'z' output above - &gt / &lt doesn't work well here.*

More information, (too much?):

```
$ man terminfo
```