# How do I restart the window manager?

Tags: window-manager

How to restart window manager so that styles (or whatever) are restored?

After doing `/etc/init.d/networking stop` they feel completely broken.

I have reinstalled lightdm.
I have restarted lightdm.
Nothing seems to help.

Is there a command line tool to reconfigure lightdm with?

Comment: This is not an answer in any way but just saying, a nicer way to stop the networking service is by `sudo service networking stop`

Comment: Related: [How can I restart x-server from the command line?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/1220/how-can-i-restart-x-server-from-the-command-line)

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You may need to restart your display manager to fix your problem.

### 11.04 and earlier.

```
sudo service gdm restart
```

### Ubuntu 11.10 and newer.

```
sudo service lightdm restart
```

`lightdm` replaces `gdm` in Ubuntu 11.10

### Ubuntu 15.04 and newer.

```
sudo service sddm restart
```

While restarting lightdm restarts the entire display manager, you may be able to resolve the issue by restarting unity or compiz (Unity is a compiz plugin).

Restarting Unity (`nohup setsid unity` OR `nohup unity --restart` on the CLI OR <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type `unity`) restarts the Unity shell.

If that doesn't work, restart compiz with `nohup compiz --replace`. You may need to restart unity again after restarting compiz.

Restarting lightdm restarts the entire display manager which is most likely to work but it will also close your running applications.  Which you need to do depends on how broken your session is.  If you can just restart Unity or Compiz, do that.  If that doesn't work, restart lightdm.

The following wiki article has additional information about fixing LightDM issues:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LightDM

Comment: Admittedly, the question is somewhat vague. But why would it be necessary to restart the display manager? The window manager is what provides window styles and restarting it is usually as effective as entering a new session. (This answer is accepted and presumably worked ...but it seems to me it does much more than is actually required to fix this problem. Restarting the computer would work, too, but is unnecessary. Restarting lightdm/gdm might also be unnecessary.)

Comment: You are right.  Restarting the window manager would presumably fix a problem with the window decorations.  However, if that doesn't work, restarting the session would the next step before power cycling the box.

Comment: **NB:** this will close all your open windows and everything in them will be lost!!!

Comment: with Ubuntu 16.04, `sudo service sddm restart` is not a recognized command, and the other options mentioned resulted in logging my user out, so restarting the machine would have worked just as poorly.

Comment: I use 19.04. With this version, the command is `sudo service gdm restart`. As far as I understand, it is so since 18.04.

Comment: On 18.10, I tried `sudo service gdm restart` while debugging [a solution to a button mapping problem](https://superuser.com/a/1446518/106977) and found, to my dismay, that the system would not let me login at all. I had to resort to rebooting anyhow.

Answer (score 39):

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type `unity`, then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> (this is the same as running `unity --replace`).

Comment: My window manager is broken, I can start programs from terminal but not from gui menu and cannot move the windows, neither by mouse nor by keyboard.Alt+F1 works, but Alt+F2 does nothing.A programme always is in front and cannot be moved backwards nor resized. I use Lubuntu 20_04 with Lxqt on old hardware.

Answer (score 5):

If everything freezes, another place you might want to restart `lightdm` from is from a TTY. This will **kill all your programs**.

- hit Ctrl + Alt + F2
- login
- `sudo service lightdm restart`

Comment: It does nothing, see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63767/how-do-i-restart-the-window-manager#comment2415440_63776), one comment above. Btw Alt+F1 brings tty1, I see the cursor but cannot type in, the screen does not accept keyboard inputs.

Answer (score 3):

**A solution for KDE:**

You have to type `kwin --replace &`

I have no idea, why @Álvaro says about `sudo service kdm restart`, but, at least on Kubuntu no such a service.

Answer (score 2):

You should type: `sudo service XXX restart`

The `XXX` should be (without quotes):

- `gdm` if you use Ubuntu 11.04 or older
- `lightdm` for Ubuntu 11.10
- `kdm` for Kubuntu
- `xdm` for Xubuntu

In case you have installed another display manager on your (K/X/L)Ubuntu you should restart the one you're using e.g. if you have installed KDE on Ubuntu (and it's the one you're using) you should restart kdm not lightdm.

In case you are not sure what to restart see the files in /etc/init.d/ and see if there is a file with a name that contains the `XXX` already mentioned, or something like YYYdm (the dm is short for "display manager").

Answer (score 1):

There are few methods to restart X.

If everything froze for example, you can kill it by pressing <kbd>Clt</kbd>+<kbd>PrtScr</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>.

Or you can restart it from terminal, as described in previous answers.

More details on how to [Restart X in Ubuntu](http://www.sudo-juice.com/ubuntu-11-10-restart-x-shortcut/).

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
setsid unity
```

If that doesn't work, try restarting X. **Note that this will crash everything:**

```
sudo service gdm restart
```

Comment: `setsid unity` seemed to launch something but styles remain broken. `sudo service gdm restart` fails with `restart: Unknown instance:`. This way it ends very often when I try to restart service, so in most cases I have to stop-start them.

Comment: This is because Oneiric uses `lightdm` by default, so you would need to type `sudo service lightdm restart`.