# Restart Only GUI Session Or Restart Only Operating System?

Tags: gui, restart

> Is It possible In Linux to restart only gui session or os ( i m not talking about restarting pc )

back in windows 98 if u want to restart the gui session or only os u just need to hold down shift key and it will restart the your gui session or only os & it work fine

[windows 98 shift + restart](https://www.google.com/search?aq=f&gcx=c&sourceid=chrome&client=ubuntu&channel=cs&ie=UTF-8&q=windows%2098#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&client=ubuntu&hs=KOl&channel=cs&source=hp&q=windows%2098%20shift%20%2b%20restart&pbx=1&oq=windows%2098%20shift%20%2b%20restart&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=2449l11815l0l12214l18l14l2l2l3l0l247l3344l2-14l18l0&fp=1&biw=1360&bih=654&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&cad=b)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Yes. There a couple of options.

1) You can [enable <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>BACKSPACE</kbd>](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10622/how-can-i-enable-ctrlaltbackspace). This three keys will work like <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SUPR</kbd>, but they will only restart the GUI.

2) From the command line (press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to get to a console) you can restart the Ubuntu display manager (which lets a user login to her preferred GUI) by entering:

```
sudo service lightdm restart
```

3) Finally you can restart just unity. It will reset your GUI (all the windows and the bars), but it will not kill any program. After the *restart* you can continue working where you left it. Enter:

```
unity --replace
```

or if you are restarting from the console (after pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>), enter:

```
DISPLAY=:0 unity --replace
```

Comment: Why do you run Unity with `sudo`?

Comment: a) You don't need to switch to a tty to restart the GUI, you can do it from within a graphical terminal just fine.

Comment: b) We used lightdm these days, so 'sudo service lightdm restart' would be more accurate

Comment: @popey: I expect that he want's to restart the GUI because it's unresponsive. That also means that unity --replace should have a DISPLAY=:0 if you need to do it from the console.

Comment: Thanks to your genius "sudo service lightdm restart" all my programs were **killed**...

Answer (score 10):

Traditionally this was accomplished in linux by using ctrl + alt + backspace. This has been disabled a few releases ago and it used to be easily enabled (with the dontzap package).

Nowdays I restart X by using the console and type:

sudo killall Xorg

Then the GUI will restart and you'll get back to your login manager. Make sure to save everything first.

Comment: FYI, if you didn't know:  The last few versions have made it easy to enable that key combination in the keyboard layout options (currently in "system settings" -> "keyboard layout" -> "layouts" -> "options..." -> "Key sequence to kill the X server").

Comment: Works nicely in Ubuntu-MATE 16.04   – (No preexisting command to assign a shortcut to under »Keyboard Shortcuts«, but since one can assign shortcust custom commands... (`⊕Add`)

Answer (score 6):

To restart your graphical session, log out and log back in.

If the system is frozen, you can use Ctrl-alt-backspace to log you out (kill your applications).

To do that , see http://ubuntuportal.com/how-to-enable-key-sequence-ctrlaltbackspace-to-kill-server-on-ubuntu-11-10/ which gives you a nice graphical walk through.

If you simply want to restart the window manager, without logging out, it depends on the window manager.

For Unity see

[How do I restart the window manager?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63767/restart-window-manager)

For gnome you hit <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and in the dialog enter <kbd>r</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

If you are running `Kubuntu` and all your window decorations have disappeared and the task-bar doesn't work, you will probably feel that your GUI session has died. You can restart it while preserving all your running programs if you already have a shell open. Just type:

```
kwin --replace &
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reinstall (`sudo apt install --reinstall` ...) a lot of packages about Xorg, GNOME, graphics card (by the way my graphics card is a MGA200 on a Dell R815), without solving the problem.

Finally, the combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to get to a console and restart the display manager by running `sudo service gdm restart` worked.