# How can I restart the GUI in Ubuntu 18?

Tags: gnome, 18.04, gui

I'd like to restart the GUI in Ubuntu 18 (using the standard Gnome interface), without rebooting. How can I do this?

I've found both these questions ([Restart Only GUI Session Or Restart Only Operating System?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/101179/restart-only-gui-session-or-restart-only-operating-system) and [How do I restart the window manager?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63767/how-do-i-restart-the-window-manager)) but none seem to apply to Ubuntu 18 (`sddm` doesn't even seem to exist anymore).

Comment: what about somethign like `sudo service x11-common restart`

Comment: @JoshuaBesneatte I believe that command restarts all the child processes of x11 too, which basically involve every user program that's been started in a session that's logged in via GUI.