# Display in applications on ubuntu 12.10 is broken - maybe theme problem

Tags: themes, display

I have a problem which looks like this:

[image: Display Example]

If you take a look at buttons "Apply", "Reset", "Close" or any other buttons or drop-downs, you will see there is no style on them.

It is a fresh install of Ubuntu 12.10 and it was working on the beginning. But after some time setting up Ubuntu I noticed the style on the elements has gone - I don't know when.

I installed compiz-settings - maybe that caused - but when I un-install nothing changes. Also checking/unchecking "window decoration" in compiz doesn't help.

---

I might found a solution in this post. I will try once I get to my computer.
[How do I restart the window manager?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63767/how-do-i-restart-the-window-manager)