# Is it possible to round the bottom corners of windows?

Tags: themes

I was just wondering if it was possible to make the bottom corners of windows in Ubuntu rounded, like a mac has.

I did find this in the theme .xml file, but when I change it to true it doesn't change anything.

```
rounded_bottom_left="false" rounded_bottom_right="false"
```

Comment: Are you using that particular theme at the moment? If so, did you reload the window manager to test the new settings (Gnome shell: ALT+F2, then simply `r`; Unity: http://askubuntu.com/questions/63767/how-do-i-restart-the-window-manager)?

Comment: yes I am using it, and yes I did reload gnome shell.  There is also  a piece of the file that has `rounded_top_left="true" rounded_top_right="true"` and when I change that it does change the top corners to square.

Answer (score 0):

NO,

it is somewhat possible, but they aren't really simple rounded corners. you need to add a noticeable border for the corners to show, I've been looking for this feature (adding rounded corners without an added border) and to my knowledge no window manager allows you to do so.