# Gnome 3 Round bottom corners of windows

Tags: gnome, themes, 15.04

Many folks have been asking to remove the top round corners on windows in gnome 3. I want to extend it to the bottom corners as well. Wondering if it is possible? There is a similar [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/250421/is-it-possible-to-round-the-bottom-corners-of-windows) asked before but it wasn't intended for the default adwaita theme which gnome 3 uses. I found the file `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/gnome-shell.css` which contains some radius stuff but I am not good at it. Wondering if someone knows how to round the bottom corners.

Comment: Ok, so which version of GNOME Shell are you running? And which version of Ubuntu (I assume the flavour is Ubuntu GNOME?)?

Comment: I am running gnome 3.14 on ubuntu 15.04

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you should proceed:

1. Look for `border-radius` property.

**Case I**: If there is just a single value assigned to it, like `border-radius: 18px;`, then it means that the borders will be rounded from all the 4 directions (Top, Right, Bottom, Left) equally (18px in this case).

**Case II**: *Shorthand Property:* If there are multiple values, like `border-radius: 18px 0px 0px 18px;`, then remember the order (Top, Right, Bottom, Left). This means that the 3d value (0px in this case), represents the bottom radius. Set it to a non-zero value!

**Note**: It should not be very hard finding `border-radius` with shorthand notation. For example, my own `gnome-shell.css` has only 9 occurences where the `border-radius` shorthand property (2nd case) is used!

Hope it helps.

Comment: so I changed `.app-view-control:last-child:rtl` to `border-radius: 18px 18px 18px 18px` but it didn't work. can you point to which value needs to be changed?

Comment: after changing the value, I did Alt-F2 and `r`

Comment: There will be multiple occurrences of the `border-radius ` property, you might have to change it for all of them!

Comment: it doesn't work

Comment: Did you try restarting your machine after saving the file. Also, you could verify that the changes are still there after the reboot!

Comment: yes. I tried Alt-F2 r as well