# What can be done when my Ubuntu completely hangs and nothing works?

Tags: unity

My system recently hung up and nothing worked. Cursor, keys, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> commands (like <kbd>Esc</kbd>, <kbd>Alt+Delete</kbd>), <kbd>Alt+F4</kbd>, everything hangs up.

Once, I saw my cousin slam some keys and a totally black screen opened, waiting for a command. It sort of opened from the top. It wasn't Type a Command box or the Terminal. Although he didn't open it when the computer hung, I guess that could still be opened?

Anyway, so what can be done **besides a reboot**?

Comment: What your cousin typed was proabably ctrl + alt + F1 (or F2 - F6). This is a real console and you can run terminal commands after you login.

Comment: Refer here :- http://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few things you can do :

- restart the window manager (see [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/63767/6228) how to do it). This will forcefully log you out
- switch to command console and kill or restart the problematic program (ctrl+alt+F1 (or F2-F6)).

Answer (score 2):

IF Single Application Stop working the Use : `xkill` And Click **X** curser on **un-Responding Application**

If System Hangs use :- **ALT+SysRq (print screen) + R E I S U B**

Where :-

**R**:  Switch to XLATE mode

**E**:  Send Terminate signal to all processes except for init

**I**:  Send Kill signal to all processes except for init

**S**:  Sync all mounted file-systems

**U**:  Remount file-systems as read-only

**B**:  Reboot

If Not Any of These :- Enter `CTRL+ALT+F1` login There,

install htop `sudo apt-get install htop`

run `htop`

find un-responding program

and type : `f7` and then `f10`

or   Enter the command : `sudo service lightdm restart`

Answer (score 1):

It seems your 'gnome-session' got hung up.

Press the combination keys `ctrl` + `alt` + `F1` (or `F2` - `F6`). Then you get a console. Login with your credentials and you will get your command prompt, then type the command:

`ps -x | grep gnome`

Find the process id of 'gnome-session' from the output and kill the session using command:

`kill -9 <process id>` (eg: If your session process id is 2183 then `kill -9 2183`)

Then your gnome session will be logged out. You can re-login and continue without rebooting.