# Programs suddenly have old window designs

Tags: unity, window-manager

I don't know what I did, but it seems that most of my programs are now using some poor old window design:

[image: LibreOffice]

[image: Gimp]

[image: Firefox]

But for example nautilus doesn't have this problem :

[image: Nautilus]

Would anyone know what this is due to?

EDIT: Here are the result of the suggested commands:

```
kenny@Computer:~$ ls /usr/share/themes
AgingGorilla  Atlanta  Crux     Emacs  HighContrast  Radiance  Simple
Ambiance      Bright   Default  Esco   Metabox       Raleigh
kenny@Computer:~$ ls ~/.themes
ls: cannot access /home/kenny/.themes: No such file or directory
kenny@Computer:~$
```

Comment: Try right clicking desktop and selecting "Change Desktop Backgroud". From the window that pops up, go to "Theme" and select a new one until you get the look you want.

Comment: I tried, it didn't change on the programs with old designs

Comment: Use Ctrl-Alt-T to open the terminal and run the commands DK Bose posted. Then edit your question above to paste their output into it.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully, you already got the solution, however, I was also having this problem and came across this question.

I also continued searching because there wasn't an answer here. The problem turns out to be that you need to restart the windows manager.

I was able to do <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> type `unity` then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. As mentioned in this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/63776/418467).

However, there is also a more detailed response above the response I linked above with more detailed commands and explanations (in case the above doesn't work).

Good luck, if you made it here! Hopefully, this works for you if you were facing the same problem as me (or maybe even the questioner).