# How to force Ubuntu to detect external display?

Tags: display

My laptop recognises external display devices if I connect them before booting the system, but many times it doesn't if I connect while the system is running. In this case, rebooting naturally solves the problem.

Is there a way to force Ubuntu to detect external displays? Opening up the display menu and pressing "Detect displays" does nothing.

Comment: Video card and driver in use?

Comment: From `lshw -c video`: it's Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller and the driver is i915.

Comment: Try logging out, going to a VC (ctrl-alt-F1) and restarting X (http://askubuntu.com/a/79587/16395). Sometime it works. Without logging out --- I never managed it.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping there'd be a way to do that without logging out.

Comment: I encountered this issue this week, with the fun added factor that rebooting wasn’t doing the trick. What did work was to use the instructions at https://askubuntu.com/questions/82140/how-can-i-boot-with-an-older-kernel-version to boot to an older kernel.

Answer (score 24):

Actually, you don't need to log out. Simply going to a VC with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd>, restarting x with `sudo service sddm restart` and 
and going back to your graphical interface with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>F7</kbd> (or <kbd>F2</kbd>) should do it.

This way, you don't lose all your windows...

Comment: This seems like it would work, since restarting my laptop works, but it doesn't.

Comment: This trick perfectly solved my problem => a case of replacing the current monitor with a new one while Ubuntu 16.04 LTE is running without reboot/logout. 

I just had to press Ctrl + Alt + F1 while my old monitor is connected, disconnect it and connect my new monitor, press Ctrl + Alt + F7 and it worked instantly!
Thank you so much!

Comment: Nice! before this I was kind of frustrated with 17.10. For me actually just doing Ctrl+Alt+F1 and logging back in is sufficient.

Comment: I'm also with 17.10, with Gnome replacing Unity. And to get back I used `Ctrl+Alt+F2`, instead of `F7`

Comment: In Ubuntu 18.04, it seems the default default graphical interface is F1. So I do Ctrl+Alt+F2, then Ctrl+Alt+F1.

Comment: Perfect! (Ubuntu 16.04)

Answer (score 19):

To enable all outputs in their default mode, run:

```
$ xrandr --auto
```

For more information, see:

https://xorg-team.pages.debian.net/xorg/howto/use-xrandr.html

Comment: `xrandr` says the display is disconnected, but it works fine in Windows.

Comment: This one worked for me. My third screen immediately started working.

Answer (score 2):

I just encountered this issue with my Dell Latitude E5550 using a port extender and two external monitors.

My problems began when I had a power failure. For silly reasons, I could only plug in one of my two monitors, so I opened up the screen display interface and de-activated the screen that didn't have power.

Awesome!

Once the power came back on the process to turn my screen back on was unintuitive. I couldn't see it in the screen display interface even after rebooting or redocking my laptop.

So I tried `$ xrandr --auto` and got Ubuntu to extend to "one" screen but duplicate to both of my externals (they are two of the same model). Amusing but not useful.

It was only when I clicked on "1 Built-in display" like in the screenshot below that I was able to select my "3rd" screen and turn it on again.

[The Screen Display Interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M73Dv.png)

Doing this flipped the two screens around for some reason and I had to rearrange them but that was easily fixed!

Comment: `lshw -c video` doesn't list monitors it lists your drivers.

Comment: You're absolutely right! I will edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I also have Dell Latitude E5550, I have one onitor via hdmi, and one via usb-c.
Then one via usb-c is not detected sometimes, and for me what it works, is unplug/plug the hdmi port in the monitor, while the rest is connected.

Comment: Just solved my issue with Dell XPS 13.

Answer (score 1):

Working solution:  Disable secure boot in the bios/efi menu.

Hello Everyone, I am coming from a TongFang GK5CN6Z and I had this issue. I noticed it was an issue after having ran the latest updates on Ubuntu. Turns out I had to disable secure boot in order for it to work.

Comment: For me it was already disabled. so I enabled it, boot on ubuntu, disabled again and then it  worked!

Comment: why would this work? are there any problems with disabling secure boot?

Answer (score 1):

I had issues with dual monitors when using `prime-select intel` when proprietary Nvidia drivers are installed. I guess either uninstalling Nvidia drivers or using only `prime-select nvidia` works, though Nvidia drivers have their own problems.

Answer (score 1):

Adapting Amanda's solution to modern ubuntu with systemd and/or other display manager than sddm :
"Actually, you don't need to log out. Simply going to a VC with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd>, restarting x with `sudo systemctl restart <your display manager>` (eg gdm or lightdm) and going back to your graphical interface with ctrl-alt-F7 (or F2) should do it.

This way, you don't lose all your windows..."

Comment: How do you find out what `<your display manager>` is?

Comment: On systems using systemd, try this : systemctl status display-manager.  More info on that question here : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20370/is-there-a-simple-linux-command-that-will-tell-me-what-my-display-manager-is

Comment: `sudo systemctl restart gdm` or `sudo systemctl restart gdm3` both killed my GNOME session (I lost my open windows), and didn’t enable my external monitor. (my problem is with external monitor not enabled after resume. Disconnecting and reconnecting the cable enables it, but I don’t want to have to do that every time)

Answer (score 0):

If the external monitor can't be detected by using `xrandr --auto`, or even by booting to different OS, reboot Ubuntu using a previous kernel. If the computer detects the monitor in the older kernel, you can go back to the latest one without any problems.

I don't know the exact reason why it works, but it definitely worked for me.

Comment: xrandr --auto closed my current GUI sessionn ! But afterwards I could use all 3 Displays: Build in Laptop and two external Display. Displays are connected via USB / DisplayLink