# ASUS ZenBook Pro Compatibilty Issues

Tags: touchpad, asus

I just got a brand new ASUS UX580GD, and have installed Ubuntu 18.04. My issue which I noticed straight away is the screenpad. It just plain doesn't work as a touchpad, probably since it isn't recognized as one. I haven't found anyone having this issue, probably since no one actually installed ubuntu on one of these. Does anyone know if there's a driver or a fix so the trackpad can at least be used (bonus points for the screen as well).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with my ASUS (UX580GD)

I fixed it by installing **Ubuntu 18.10**.

First, i tried it without installing Touch-pad worked fine.

Then, when i installed it, and after the first reboot the system freezes after login. *(nothing at all responds)*

I chose to boot on **rescue mode** and executed this command:

`$ sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`

Once the installation is concluded, i rebooted the system and my problem is solved.

Comment: Screenpad work in my UX580GD too, but there's still and issue with screenpad which has no drivers.

I've allready sent via apport bug here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/+bug/1846090

Answer (score 0):

Try to combine [Touchscreen](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touchscreen) with external display ([How to force Ubuntu to detect external display?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/707422/how-to-force-ubuntu-to-detect-external-display))

Answer (score 0):

ScreenPad lights up in Xubuntu 19.10. Last Kubuntu shows logo in screenpad while boots, but there's no software for Linux systems