# Ubuntu uses only the top left quarter of the screen

Tags: screen

I'm using Ubuntu 16 live on two PCs and both show an image only on the upper left quarter of the screen. How can I resize it since I cannot go to settings the normal way?

[image]

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of the terminal command `lspci -nnk | grep -A2 VGA` and `xrandr`? Thanks.

Comment: If you cannot get to the terminal via the GUI, you can press Ctrl + Alt + F1 to change to the vt, and press Ctrl + Alt + F7 to get back. Sometimes doing this also (temporarily) fixes problems like this.

Comment: I've got the same issue on Pop!_OS 22.04. [Here's a gist](https://gist.github.com/dhimmel/e3aadfa7cccee684b4c4b47214f0dddb) with output for the commands mentioned by @DavidFoerster.

Comment: Did you find how to fix this please?

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same issue on Ubuntu 16.04 when launching some Steam games.

The only solution I have found is to [restart the display manager](https://askubuntu.com/a/79587), at the cost of logging out and losing the session.

Comment: I do not have enough reputation to comment on the original question... for me the output of  `lspci -nnk | grep -A2 VGA` is: 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller [8086:0166] (rev 09)
        DeviceName: Intel(R) Graphics 4000
        Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller [103c:18f9]

Comment: `xrandr`: Can't open display