# Launcher going all black. What is wrong with it?

Tags: unity, launcher

All the icons in the Unity Launcher is blank.

[image]

Need Help!

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the above question

Comment: @waltinator I don't think that's quite what is happening here. The computer boots up and does display the unity desktop however all the icons are blacked out. That answer assumes that the screen boots up completely black.

Comment: @kisan Did you install icon packs or changed settings related to that?

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to restart unity? Adding from the second answer found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63767/how-do-i-restart-the-window-manager):

Hold down `ctr`+`alt` and press `t`. This will bring up the terminal. Then type `unity`. This will restart unity and hopefully fix the issue.