# Auto-run a service on user log-in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, gnome, startup

I want to restart the desktop manager service automatically every time the user logs into the PC. I don't need it just on startup, but more importantly on each log in after that, such as after hibernating or after locking the screen.

How I assume I will make it work is by running a script on every login that will automatically restart the desktop manager.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, `~/.profile` would execute after login, hibernate / suspend see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/423524/script-that-is-executed-after-resuming-from-hibernation https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/619987/stop-systemd-service-before-suspend-start-again-after-resume?noredirect=1&lq=1 and https://askubuntu.com/questions/63767/how-do-i-restart-the-window-manager

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by a "desktop manager service." And a login is very different from an unlock. We can provide better advice if your question is more clear, or if you describe your actual problem that had led you to this preferred solution.