# I have to restart lightdm after run

Tags: xubuntu, lightdm

After starting the system, i've a black screen (without any screen backlight), then i have to switch to tty6 (ctrl+alt+f6), login and restart the lightdm:

```
sudo service lightdm restart
```

I'm using xfce.

Comment: Can you please [add](http://askubuntu.com/posts/365719/edit) to you r question what version of xubuntu you are using?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I restart x-server from the command line?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/1220/how-can-i-restart-x-server-from-the-command-line)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1st Way to solve your issue:**

**Try to reconfigure lightdm** (if it doesn't solve your issue then go for *Alternate way mentioned below.*)

- Open terminal(<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and execute following command:

  ```
  sudo dpkg-reconfigre lightdm
  ```
- Then chose `lightdm` from the list. As shown below:

[image: lighdm]
<sub>(source: [akamaihd.net](https://fbcdn-sphotos-f-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-frc3/1378375_454948661291695_937916838_n.jpg))</sub>

- Restart your system:

  ```
  sudo reboot now
  ```

It  should fix your issue.

**an alternate way, which would solve your issue. Give it a try.**

Installing a new display manager can fix your problem. Steps to install **GDM**(a display manager much like **lightdm**):

- Open terminal(<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and execute following commands:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install gdm
  sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
  ```

  then chose `gdm` from the list:

[image: gdm]
<sub>(source: [akamaihd.net](https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn2/1390653_454948664625028_2140985254_n.jpg))</sub>

```
    sudo reboot
```

- If it's still not fixed, try removing `lightdm` after installing `gdm`:

  ```
  sudo apt-get remove --purge lightdm
  sudo reboot
  ```

Reply if something goes wrong..

Comment: After purge remove lightdm, i'd to change xfce theme back to graybird, but it's works. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

If you are booting windows with ubuntu i have same problem then i tried everything referred from sites.finally nothing is worked for me.
 so one thing is worked for me.

1. do not choose the default ubuntu os.
2. click on advanced option for ubuntu
3. choose the os option like "Ubuntu 16.04 .....(Systemed)"

this will boot your ubuntu os normally. and it works for me also it saves your time to everytime restart lightdm service.