# Some fonts seem to be missing using xboard

Tags: fonts

I recently installed a chess program called xboard. I tried to open it from the terminal and it gave me the following error.

```
dineshkumar@dineshkumar-desktop:~$ xboard 
xboard: no fonts match pattern -*-helvetica-bold-r-normal--*-*-*-*-*-*-*-* 
Some fonts seem to be missing in your system, you should install either xfonts-100dpi or
xfonts-75dpi and then restart Xorg to get xboard running.
See http://bugs.debian.org/504077 and http://bugs.debian.org/562726 for more information.
```

What does this means and how do I rectify it and run xboard?

Answer (score 2):

Need some fonts.

```
sudo apt-get install xfonts-75dpi
```

Then restart xorg. Save your file and work before, my openbox get an error during restart lxdm.
Howto, see [How to restart X Window Server from command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1220/how-can-i-restart-x-server-from-the-command-line)

Or, just restart your computer.