# Launching programs after hostname change returns error _IceTransSocketUNIXConnect: could not connect to local-host

Tags: hostname, sockets

After changing the hostname on 14.04 I cannot launch unetbootin, attempting to launch the application from bash returns:

`_IceTransSocketUNIXConnect: Cannot connect to non-local host OLDHOSTNAME
_IceTransSocketUNIXConnect: Cannot connect to non-local host OLDHOSTNAME
Qt: Session management error: Could not open network socket`

Output from `hostname` `cat /etc/hostname` and `cat /etc/hosts` all confirm that the hostname is correct. I've also rebooted the system since making the change to confirm everything loaded with the new settings.

I am at a loss, any help is greatly appreciated! Also, could anyone provide some background on what IceTransSocketUNIXConnect is and how it works? Is it anything like Winsock?

Answer (score 7):

It appears this error stems from the ~/.ICEauthority file. You can use the command `iceauth list` list your entries. In my case the old hostname included `localhost`, replace this with your old hostname.

e.g. `iceauth list | grep localhost`:

> XSMP "" unix/localhost@localdomain:/tmp/.ICE-unix/2640 MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 7035f3aebe650bd72315b76819267a9d
>   XSMP "" local/localhost@localdomain:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/2640 MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 abe16eba34a1cf69087aff88bdd14a1a
>   ICE "" local/localhost@localdomain:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/2640 MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 1e69a0d48b1f1375167c79bffbbfa06e
>   ICE "" unix/localhost@localdomain:/tmp/.ICE-unix/2640 MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 f91ab2525bf0000159161db41df1aa0c

2 options:

1. Simple - Delete the ~/.ICEauthority file and restart machine or display manager. ~/.ICEauthority will be regenerated with your new hostname.
2. Advanced - Use `iceauth remove` to remove the bad entries and then restart your display manager (14.04 default = lightdm). Just copy paste the line from your grep above into the examples below, it removes both XSMP and ICE protocol entries.

   - `iceauth -v remove netid=unix/localhost@localdomain:/tmp/.ICE-unix/2640`
   - `iceauth -v remove netid=local/localhost@localdomain:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/2640`
   - `iceauth list | grep localhost` # Confirm they are removed.
   - `sudo restart lightdm` # @see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1220/how-to-restart-x-window-server-from-command-line/1222#1222) for more details or if this doesn't work for you

---

Further reading from `man iceauth`:

> **list**
>
> List (print) entries in the authority file. You may specify optional
>   modifiers as below to specify which entries are listed.
>
> list [ protocol_name ] [ protocol_data ] [ netid ] [ authname ]
>
> **remove**
>
> Remove entries from the authority file.
>
> remove [ protocol_name ] [ protocol_data ] [ netid ] [ authname ]

sources:
https://superuser.com/questions/714015/accidentally-deleted-iceauthority-and-xauthority-files
https://codeyarns.com/2015/03/23/cannot-connect-to-non-local-host-error/
https://linux.die.net/man/1/iceauth
[How to restart X Window Server from command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1220/how-to-restart-x-window-server-from-command-line/1222)