# How to assign a name to a workspace?

Tags: 14.04, workspaces, workspace-switcher

I already tried to right click on workspace switcher, but it doesn't show anything.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do that with Compiz.  To install, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install compiz compizconfig-settings-manager compiz-plugins
```

Once installed, run the program, and navigate to Window Management --> Workspace Naming, and change the names to whatever you want.

[image]

**Edit**

I just installed using the command above on 14.04, and 16.04, and it works.

[image]

Comment: Does not work in 14.04 LTS: https://ibin.co/2hnS9jImQN0n.png

Comment: Did you install using the whole command mentioned in the answer?    I just installed on 14.04 & 16.04, and it works on both.  Let me know.

Comment: Not sure, it was already installed (I guess I did this long ago?)

Comment: `compiz-plugins` was missing. Now it works! Thanks!

Comment: In order to get this to work in 17.04, I had to [restart X Window server](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1220/how-to-restart-x-window-server-from-command-line) after changing the names.

Comment: Is there a way to display the workspace name when using workspace switcher? (So I can see easily which is which, before switching)

Comment: Confirmed to work in 16.04