# Screen Brighness always come back to 1

Tags: laptop, brightness

I am new to Ubuntu.
recently, I changed to the Xfce desktop. Everything went well, except for the brightness which couldn't be set using the keyboard. After some tries, I solved the pb with a script linked to the keyboard, that set the brightness using  "*xrandr --output [my screen] --brightness [value]*". It went well.

I restarted my computer the next day and IT happened: the brightness changed every 1 second to a little darker or brighter setting. like, every second. Unusable.
I searched on the internet I found this : [random event changes screen brightness automatically](https://askubuntu.com/questions/793829/random-event-changes-screen-brightness-automatically). (image :https://i.stack.imgur.com/oEh0o.png)

I followed the instructions, and restarted my computer. The brightness was fixed, but **the brightness is now fixed to the maximum permanently** (the max being 1, in the xrandr config). Meaning, if I change the value using xrandr, it go back to the maximum almost instantly.
I deleted the "fix" (in the *10-quirks.conf*), but nothing changed.

can you help me ?

```
Computer hardware (using inxi command in a terminal): 
    CPU: Dual Core Intel Core i5-6200U (-MT MCP-) 
    speed/min/max: 800/400/2800 MHz Kernel: 5.8.0-38-generic x86_64 Up: 39m 
    Mem: 2070.5/3766.8 MiB (55.0%) Storage: 465.76 GiB (40.2% used) Procs: 317 
    Shell: bash 5.0.17 inxi: 3.0.38
```

Comment: Try whether you can set the brightness with the utility `light` (sudo apt install light). This may work a lot better than xrand.

Comment: Work perfectly! But only on 'sudo' mod... How can I fix this problem, and make this work without ? (in order to increase or decrease the brightness with my keyboard)
Currently, if I put the command "sudo light -v3 -A 10" (which work in a terminal for raise the brightness by 5%) , It open a terminal in order to prompt the 'sudo' password. 
I tried using a .sh document, with the right command inside, but here again I lust use sudo mod either while opening the document, or in the command inside. 

Every hint is welcome !

Comment: In that case, I will post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your hardware, you may have more or less luck with brightness. Ideally, brightness is just remembered between boots.

You could try your luck with a utility `light`. Install it with the command

```
sudo apt install light
```

To be able to run it as normal user, set the suid bit:

```
sudo chmod u+s  $(which light)
```

This utility can save and restore brightness values.

Although everything works fine for me out of the box, this is a great utility that I use to be able to set the change in brightness in smaller increments. Brightness is increased with (numbers are between 0 and 100%)

```
light -A 1
```

and decreased with

```
light -U 1
```

You can set a minimum brightness, so you are not at risk to fully darken the screen:

```
light -N 1.95
```

Read the `man` pages for all the options.

Comment: It worked perfectly! Thank you very much. the `sudo chmod u+s  $(which light)` part is very strange to me, but it worked perfectly ! And that is all that matter. Thank you very much again! :)

Comment: Using `$(which light)` is a handy shortcut.