# Brightness automatically goes to full whenever I log in

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, brightness

Whenever I log in to Ubuntu, the brightness automatically goes to full. I'm using ubuntu 20.04 LTS with dual boot.

Any solution for this?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1312008/screen-brighness-always-come-back-to-1/1312197#1312197 and if light is not remember (I have only just now installed it) you can set a startup script for login like light 50   , note from light --help -O option to save it

Comment: yep it did not save for me, so requires a script to be run at startup.

Answer (score 1):

This can often be fixed by adding a setting to your Grub configuration. Try this:

1. Open Terminal (if it is not already open)
2. Edit the Grub configuration file:

   ```
   $ sudo vi /etc/default/grub
   ```

   ***Note:** Feel free to use any text editor you prefer, so long as you are editing the file with* `sudo`.
3. Find the line that starts `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` and add `acpi_backlight=vendor`. This should give you a line that looks similar to this:

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"
   ```

   ***Note:** Your line may be longer with additional settings if you have an Nvidia video device or other hardware.*
4. Save the file and update Grub:

   ```
   $ sudo update-grub
   ```
5. Reboot.

This should resolve the issue.

Comment: It didn't work for me!