# Turning Off Automatic Brightness in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: brightness

Just updated my install of Ubuntu to 17.10 today. The brightness keeps setting itself randomly. It'll either shut off the screen, or put it about halfway up. This is incredibly frustrating as I like to work a minimum brightness. 
Is there anyway I can turn this feature off?

I've looked through the Preferences->power manager menu, but I've already set it to do nothing while my laptop is plugged in. I don't know the source of the problem, so I haven't been able to look through the terminal to fix anything.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you try to set and control brightness via *xbacklight*?

Basic commands of xbacklight are:

```
sudo apt install xbacklight
xbacklight -get
xbacklight -set insert-here-a-percentage-value-from-1%-to-100%
```

I had the same issue after installing nVidia drivers and the brightness control was gone. With xbacklight you can even gradually increase or decrease brightness and add the relative commands (see help) to keyboard shotcuts.

Comment: I did as you asked, but using: xbacklight -set -10% and xbacklight -set -100% produces the same effect, no change. Also done without percentage markers.

Comment: Are you using nVidia or noveau drivers? Are you using the deafult Wayland or Xorg?

Can you post the output of this command:

echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE

Comment: I'm using Nvidia drivers with the x11 environment. The command output is "x11"

Comment: Hope this can help: https://askubuntu.com/questions/777754/brightness-randomly-up-and-down-on-msi-laptop/808785#808785

Comment: It worked! What a weird bug. Thanks for all of the help!