# Can't disable auto brightness on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: brightness, 22.04

I'm looking for any solutions disable auto-brightness on Ubuntu, I'm so tired with it!

OS: Ubuntu 22.04
Machine: MSI-Modern-15-A5M
CPU: AMD® Ryzen 5 5500u with radeon graphics × 12
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Brightness randomly up and down on MSI laptop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/777754/brightness-randomly-up-and-down-on-msi-laptop)

Comment: @Esther, thank you but thís way does not solve my problem!