# MSI modern 14b5m screen brightness changing randomly

Tags: 22.04, brightness, msi, automatic

I'm having problems with the screen brightness moving up and down randomly, with no input from me, I have checked automatic brightness but that option doesn't shows up.
Tried this solution to a similar problem found in this link: [Brightness randomly up and down on MSI laptop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/777754/brightness-randomly-up-and-down-on-msi-laptop/808785#808785)
wich says that adding these lines in /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-quirks.conf, the problem will be solved:

```
Section "InputClass"
 Identifier "Spooky Ghosts"
 MatchProduct "Video Bus"
 Option "Ignore" "on"
EndSection
```

But it didn't solved the issue.

I've tried to look at the evtest Video Bus outputs to see what's happening and found this:
[Output received from sudo evtest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JeJ0I.png)

It seems to be a Video Bus thing, and I have the event ID, but I don't know what to do whit that info, so if you have any clues or solutions for this, let me know, thanks for reading this.

Answer (score 0):

So I have found a workarround to this problem. It seems to be a problem with the Fn keys that change the brightness. If you don't press them in your session, the problem will not show up. So I decided to simply not use them by using "light" from terminal, and then add a keyboard shortcut to change the brightness whitout using the usual hotkeys (wich are f9 and f10 in this laptop).
These are the steps I did:

```
sudo apt install light
```

for light installation, then you can adjust the brightness with the commands below easily from terminal:

```
sudo light -A 5 # increase brightness
sudo light -U 5 # decrease brightness
```

So, by editing /etc/sudoers with`sudo visudo` and adding this line, you can use this command with no password needed (so you can assign it to a keyboard shortcut):

```
<username> ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/light #change it to your username
```

Now, you just have to create a keyboard custom shortcut with the commands shown above (using the keyboard config in the preferences of ubuntu)

p.s.: be sure to deactivate your hotkey simple activation with "fn + esc".

Answer (score 0):

I have the same laptop model and have experienced the same issue. The described X11 quirks change method didn't resolve the issue as well at first.

But after considering the [Brightness randomly up and down on MSI laptop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/777754/brightness-randomly-up-and-down-on-msi-laptop?noredirect=1&lq=1) top answer's comment to move the quirks file to `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-quirks.conf` I have found that such phantom input events no longer take affect and now my laptop doesn't experience random screen brightness changes. Better, my fn keys are still functioning so there are no tradeoff.