# MSI Laptop brightness randomly changes after using function keys

Tags: laptop, msi

I'm currently running Ubuntu (Gnome Desktop) on my MSI Modern 14 laptop, but I have this weird issue that my screen brightness keeps on changing randomly after using function keys to change it.

I tried the solution in [**this thread**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/777754/brightness-randomly-up-and-down-on-msi-laptop/808785#808785), and it worked on the XOrg session, but I don't know **how to do the configuration on Wayland**.

I was hoping you could help me.

Comment: Does this happen with any particular function keys? Also, what model is your computer?

Comment: @Logan Brightness function keys causes the issue and my laptop model is MSI Modern 14 B4MW!