# Making Keyboard Shortcuts act Universally (No Matter the Language)

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, language-support

I would be really grateful if someone could give me some guidance!
I am trying to set up some shortcuts. The thing is that Ubuntu responds differently, according to the input language, specified by the user. Like yesterday, when I tried to set up the shortcut for thr terminal, hitting the letters alt+c the output was alt+greek_psi, taken from the greek language that I had at the time.
As I have imagined, later inputs for the terminal corresponded only when I had switched to the greek keyboard.
I have distro hoped for many years. This is something that I am facing for the first time. Linux mint as an example, when I pressed alt+c, no matter the language was, was behaving "universally".
How can I have again the same behavior here, so my different shortcuts act "as is" no matter the language interface?
I beg for your help!
Phil

Answer (score 0):

On the default Ubuntu Terminal <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> does "Capitalize a letter on the cursor and move cursor at the end of the word."

You may use a global shortcut by editing `System Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts`
You should consider not to use the combinations already in use.

Unfortunately, I haven't seen someone finds a way to display a list of all the shortcuts used in the system and applications. My best guess is to look at the `Keyboard > Shortcuts` and choose the most useless one for you and take the combination for your use. It should work globally.

---

In the case, you are looking for how to type Greek letters without switching keyboard layout. Here's my favorite way.

The Greek θ letter is a unicode character U+03B8.

<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> 03B8 <kbd>Space</kbd>

This types Greek theta, it's convenient for mathematician or scripting a such scientical document. You may also want to use π U+03C0.

If you often use this, please register this as a global shortcut.
There are many ways to do so, but each one has some problems preventing to work on some application. I think <kbd>Compose</kbd> key is easiest.

Reference : [Compose "dead_greek" with compose key](https://askubuntu.com/questions/787113/compose-dead-greek-with-compose-key)

Comment: Thank you, for this detailed answer. I really appreciate it!