# How to restart X Window Server from command line on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: command-line, 18.04, xorg

How to I achieve a GUI restart in ubuntu 18.04 using Gnome on the standard X Windows Server.

Seems like the [old question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1220/how-to-restart-x-window-server-from-command-line) doesn't apply anymore.

Comment: I updated the answer there.