# Ubuntu 18.04 — icon menu gets stuck open, any way to fix that without having to reboot?

Tags: gnome, icons, dock

I am running in this problem once in a while where I click on an icon in my dock and instead of just going to the app. it opens the menu and leaves that menu open forever. Closing or restarting the app. doesn't help. The menu gets updated dynamically as required, but it still stays opened.

Trying to click on any of the menu items fails because the clicks "go through" (so the mouse clicks are not sent to the menu which I think is the main reason why it fails).

Here is an example when it occurred to me with Firefox:

[image]

Note: I started with a fresh Ubuntu 18.04 install (no upgrade from older versions). So that would not be it, although I may have something installed that causes the side effect. It only started to happen recently, though (Oct 2020).

P.S. Clicking on other icons works just fine. Their menu shows up and gets hidden as expected. So doing so is not going to help to hide the one menu that's stuck open.

P.S. 2 -- when there is no window behind that menu, clicking a menu item gets the mouse stuck to where I have to use a lot of keyboard tricks to get it release back. So it's super annoying. I'd like to learn of a way to fix it without having to reboot!

P.S. 3 -- I run [this command](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1220/how-to-restart-x-window-server-from-command-line):

```
sudo systemctl restart display-manager
```

And that menu is still open!?

P.S. 4 -- The Log Out option fails, it looks like it gets stuck (i.e. it probably waits on some lock which is a deadlock) so I have to forcibly reboot. I would imagine that a lock is not going to be fixed with any random hack. Oh well...

P.S. 5 -- I also reported this as a [bug on launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1902385).

Comment: I'm having the same problem on manjaro gnome

Comment: @Jesbus If you would follow my link to launchpad and let them know, it would be great. We need at least 2 people reporting the same bug to have a chance of them looking at it.