# Keyboard and Mouse Clicks not recognized - Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

Tags: gnome-shell

I have a problem that occurs roughly once every 90 minutes on a VM guest running Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS.

- System stops responding to any keyboard keypress or mouse click
- Mouse movement still recognized
- SSH and VNC still connect
- The system can be interacted with normally via SSH
- VNC Mouse clicks and keyboard keypresses are not recognized, but mouse movement is recognized
- Virtual keypresses through VNC and VMware host controls eg. `send ctrl+alt+del` are not recognized
- vmtools seems to be working properly, eg. changing the size of the guest window causes the windows inside the guest operating system to re-size

There isn't anything obviously using a lot of resources and apart from not being able to click or type, the system seems to be running without problem.

I've tried:

- [Restarting display-manager](https://askubuntu.com/a/1222)
- [Restarting gnome-shell](https://ttboj.wordpress.com/2014/05/29/restarting-gnome-shell-via-ssh/)
- Restarting vm tools on the guest: `systemctl restart vmtoolsd`

So far the only thing that re-enables keypresses and mouse-clicks is rebooting the guest VM.

The host is running Windows 11, with VMWare Workstation 17

Is there a way to recover mouse & keyboard control without restarting Ubuntu, or a way to prevent the issue from re-occurring?

Answer (score 0):

It just sounds that the guest os doesn't have much memory allocation size.
If possible, raise the RAM size it provided.

Comment: The guest OS reports plenty of free RAM. 

The problem persists after killing the desktop environment and any running applications.

The guest OS is running fine and smooth. 

The only problem is that mouse clicks and keyboard keypresses aren't being handled.